# A trivial command line utility for trimming whitespace from lines in C - follow-up 2

Tags: c, console, unix

The **previous** iteration at [A trivial command line utility for trimming whitespace from lines in C - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/a-trivial-command-line-utility-for-trimming-whitespace-from-lines-in-c-follow)

**Note**: the next iteration at [A trivial command line utility for trimming whitespace from lines in C - follow-up 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86491/a-trivial-command-line-utility-for-trimming-whitespace-from-lines-in-c-follow)

Now my code looks like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HELP_FLAG           "-h"
#define VERSION_FLAG        "-v"
#define FLAG_DESC           "%-5s"
#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 64
#define FALSE               0
#define TRUE                (~FALSE)

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine removes all leading and trailing whitespace from a string,      *
* doing that in-place and using only one pass over the string.                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static char* trim_inplace(char* start)
{
    while (isspace(*start))
    {
        ++start;
    }

    int whitespace_begin_index = -1;

    // At this point, we have dealt with leading whitespace.
    for (int index = 0; start[index]; ++index)
    {
        if (!isspace(start[index]))
        {
            whitespace_begin_index = -1;
        }
        else if (whitespace_begin_index == -1)
        {
            whitespace_begin_index = index;
        }
    }

    if (whitespace_begin_index != -1)
    {
        // Cut the trailing whitespace off.
        start[whitespace_begin_index] = '\0';
    }

    return start;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Attempts to expand the line buffer. If succeeded, returns the pointer to the *
* line buffer. Otherwise NULL is returned.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static char* try_expand(char* buffer, int* p_buffer_length)
{
    *p_buffer_length *= 2;
    return realloc(buffer, *p_buffer_length);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Processes a single line and handles everything needed for dealing with lines *
* of arbitrary length.                                                         *
*******************************************************************************/
static int process_line(char** p_buffer, int* p_buffer_length, FILE* file)
{
    int chars_read = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        // The delta is for appending the next text chunk at correct position.
        int delta = chars_read > 0;
        char* ret = fgets(*p_buffer + chars_read - delta,
                          *p_buffer_length - chars_read + delta,
                          file);

        if (!ret)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Find out whether we have a newline character, which would imply that
        // we have an entire line read.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < *p_buffer_length; ++i)
        {
            if ((*p_buffer)[i] == '\n')
            {
                (*p_buffer)[i] = '\0';
                puts(trim_inplace(*p_buffer));
                return TRUE;
            }

        }

        chars_read = *p_buffer_length;
        char* new_buffer;

        // Once here, the current line does not fit in 'p_buffer'. Expand the
        // array by doubling its capacity.
        if (!(new_buffer = try_expand(*p_buffer, p_buffer_length)))
        {
            perror("Could not expand the line buffer");
            free(*p_buffer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            *p_buffer = new_buffer;
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Processes a file.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void process_file(char** p_buffer, int* p_buffer_length, FILE* file)
{
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        process_line(p_buffer, p_buffer_length, file);
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the help message and exits.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_help()
{
    printf("Usage: trim [" HELP_FLAG "] [" VERSION_FLAG "] "          \
           "[FILE1, [FILE2, [...]]]\n"                                \
           "    " FLAG_DESC " Print this help message and exit.\n"    \
           "    " FLAG_DESC " Print the version message and exit.\n"  \
           "    If no files specified, reads from standard input.\n",
           HELP_FLAG,
           VERSION_FLAG);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the version string.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_version()
{
    printf("trim 1.618\n" \
           "By Rodion \"rodde\" Efremov 09.04.2015 Helsinki\n");
}


/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the erroneous flag.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_bad_flag(const char* flag)
{
    printf("Unknown flag \"%s\"\n", flag);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Checks the flags.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void check_flags(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], HELP_FLAG) == 0)
        {
            print_help();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], VERSION_FLAG) == 0)
        {
            print_version();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (argv[i][0] == '-')
        {
            print_bad_flag(argv[i]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The entry point for a trivial line trimmer.                                  *
*******************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    check_flags(argc, argv);

    int buffer_length = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    char* buffer = malloc(buffer_length);

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        // If realloc changes the location of memory, we need to know this.
        process_file(&buffer, &buffer_length, stdin);
        fclose(stdin);
        free(buffer);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (!file)
        {
            perror("Error opening a file");
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        process_file(&buffer, &buffer_length, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```

I have done the following:

1. No casting types with `malloc`/`realloc`
2. `sizeof(char)` assumed to be 1
3. Constants used only once are not `#defined`
4. Variables are declared as close to their usage as possible.
5. The whitespace trimming function implements a state machine doing only one pass over the input string.
6. The *linked list of chars* -idea removed. Instead, a buffer is doubled everytime a new line does not fit.

Comment: Are you aware of [`<stdbool.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdbool/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't have to define custom true/false constants and boolean types. C99 made [`<stdbool.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html) standard. It will provide you with `bool`, `true` and `false`, which are quite handy for return values and well... booleans!
- The downside of hardcoding the name `trim` in the help/info strings is that if the name of the binary is changed/aliased it will still print `trim` in the help run. If you use `argv[0]`, this issue goes away. Unless of course the hardcoded string is the intended behavior.
- Consider using a standard argument parsing tool such as `getopt` or `argp_parse`. No need to reinvent the wheel when such great tools already exist. See a list [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html).
- If I compile this with all warnings enabled on Clang (`-Wall`, `-Wextra`) I get the output:

  ```
  test.c:82:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
          for (size_t i = 0; i < *p_buffer_length; ++i)
                             ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  test.c:159:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
                         ~ ^ ~~~~
  test.c:198:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
                         ~ ^ ~~~~
  ```

  You have a few `size_t`s comparing against `int`s. This is harmless 99% of the time, but it wouldn't be a hassle being consistent and using the same type for both variables in this case. `p_buffer_length` is the length of an array, so it would be more correct as `size_t`.