# A trivial command line utility for trimming whitespace from lines in C - follow-up 3

Tags: c, unix

The **previous** iteration at [A trivial command line utility for trimming whitespace from lines in C - follow-up 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86377/a-trivial-command-line-utility-for-trimming-whitespace-from-lines-in-c-follow)

Now my code looks like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define HELP_FLAG           "-h"
#define VERSION_FLAG        "-v"
#define FLAG_DESC           "%-5s"
#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 64

/*******************************************************************************
* This routine removes all leading and trailing whitespace from a string,      *
* doing that in-place and using only one pass over the string.                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static char* trim_inplace(char* start)
{
    while (isspace(*start))
    {
        ++start;
    }

    int whitespace_begin_index = -1;

    // At this point, we have dealt with leading whitespace.
    for (int index = 0; start[index]; ++index)
    {
        if (!isspace(start[index]))
        {
            whitespace_begin_index = -1;
        }
        else if (whitespace_begin_index == -1)
        {
            whitespace_begin_index = index;
        }
    }

    if (whitespace_begin_index != -1)
    {
        // Cut the trailing whitespace off.
        start[whitespace_begin_index] = '\0';
    }

    return start;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Attempts to expand the line buffer. If succeeded, returns the pointer to the *
* line buffer. Otherwise NULL is returned.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
static char* try_expand(char* buffer, int* p_buffer_length)
{
    *p_buffer_length *= 2;
    return realloc(buffer, *p_buffer_length);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Processes a single line and handles everything needed for dealing with lines *
* of arbitrary length.                                                         *
*******************************************************************************/
static void process_line(char** p_buffer, int* p_buffer_length, FILE* file)
{
    int chars_read = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        // The delta is for appending the next text chunk at correct position.
        int delta = chars_read > 0;
        char* ret = fgets(*p_buffer + chars_read - delta,
                          *p_buffer_length - chars_read + delta,
                          file);

        if (!ret)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Find out whether we have a newline character, which would imply that
        // we have an entire line read.
        for (int i = 0; i < *p_buffer_length; ++i)
        {
            if ((*p_buffer)[i] == '\n')
            {
                (*p_buffer)[i] = '\0';
                puts(trim_inplace(*p_buffer));
                return;
            }

        }

        chars_read = *p_buffer_length;
        char* new_buffer;

        // Once here, the current line does not fit in 'p_buffer'. Expand the
        // array by doubling its capacity.
        if (!(new_buffer = try_expand(*p_buffer, p_buffer_length)))
        {
            perror("Could not expand the line buffer");
            free(*p_buffer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            *p_buffer = new_buffer;
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Processes a file.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void process_file(char** p_buffer, int* p_buffer_length, FILE* file)
{
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        process_line(p_buffer, p_buffer_length, file);
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* If name contains directories, gets rid of them and returns a sole name of    *
* the executable file.                                                         *
*******************************************************************************/
static const char* get_short_program_name(const char* name)
{
    size_t len = strlen(name);
    const char* ret = name;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (name[i] == '/')
        {
            ret = &name[i + 1];
        }
    }

    return ret; 
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the help message and exits.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_help(const char* program_name)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [" HELP_FLAG "] [" VERSION_FLAG "] "            \
           "[FILE1, [FILE2, [...]]]\n"                                \
           "    " FLAG_DESC " Print this help message and exit.\n"    \
           "    " FLAG_DESC " Print the version message and exit.\n"  \
           "    If no files specified, reads from standard input.\n",
           get_short_program_name(program_name),
           HELP_FLAG,
           VERSION_FLAG);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the version string.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_version()
{
    printf("trim 1.6180\n" \
           "By Rodion \"rodde\" Efremov 10.04.2015 Helsinki\n");
}


/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the erroneous flag.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_bad_flag(const char* flag)
{
    printf("Unknown flag \"%s\"\n", flag);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Checks the flags.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void check_flags(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "vh")) != -1)
    {
        switch (c) 
        {
            case 'v':
                print_version();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;

            case 'h':
                print_help(argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;

            case '?':
                print_bad_flag((char*) &optopt);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;

            default:
                abort();
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* The entry point for a trivial line trimmer.                                  *
*******************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    check_flags(argc, argv);

    int buffer_length = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    char* buffer = malloc(buffer_length);

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        // If realloc changes the location of memory, we need to know this.
        process_file(&buffer, &buffer_length, stdin);
        fclose(stdin);
        free(buffer);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (!file)
        {
            perror("Error opening a file");
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        process_file(&buffer, &buffer_length, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    free(buffer);
}
```

I have done the following:

1. Boolean stuff removed as it is no longer used.
2. Whenever printing the help message, the actual name of the binary is used.
3. Used `getopt` for parsing command line arguments.
4. Fixed `size_t` versus `int` warnings.

Comment: You might want to add an explanation of why you're doing this — presumably it's a learning exercise, otherwise you'd just use something like `sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//; s/[[:space:]]+$//;'`

Comment: `get_short_program_name` seems to do the same as `basename (3)`

Answer (score 2):

1. Rather than `while (!feof(file)) { process_line(p_buffer,  p_buffer_length, file); }`, consider having `process_line()` return a value that can be tested.  `fgets()` returns `NULL` for at least 3 reasons: `EOF`, input error, scant buffer.  Calling routine only looks for the common `feof()`
2. `main()` does not check for a `NULL` result in `char* buffer = malloc(buffer_length);`, yet later code dereferences that pointer also without checking.
3. Pedantically, `isspace(*start))` is potential undefined behavior (UB) when `char` is signed.  `is...()` functions take a `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  Solution: `isspace((unsigned char) *start))`
4. String array indexes as well as memory allocation work with type `size_t` and not `int` like this code employs.  This impacts portability/correctness once the array size exceeds the minium of `INT_MAX`,`SIZE_MAX`.
5. In `try_expand()`, `*p_buffer_length *= 2;` does not check for potential overflow.  `return realloc(buffer, *p_buffer_length);` does not check for memory allocation failure but leaves that for the calling code.  IMO, the exit handling should be in `try_expand()`.
6. `void print_version()` should be `void print_version(void)` so a complier properly complains if `print_version()` called with a parameter as in `print_version("123")`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the top…

The `trim_inplace()` function reads more naturally if you work with pointers instead of indexes.  In particular, `whitespace_begin_index` is awkwardly named, and using `-1` as a special value is less elegant than using `NULL`.

```
/*******************************************************************************
* This routine removes all leading and trailing whitespace from a string,      *
* doing that in-place and using only one pass over the string.                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static char* trim_inplace(char* start)
{
    // Skip leading whitespace
    while (isspace(*start)) {
        ++start;
    }

    // Cut off trailing whitespace
    char *cutoff = NULL;
    for (char *p = start; *p; p++)
    {
        if (!isspace(*p))
        {
            cutoff = NULL;
        }
        else if (!cutoff)
        {
            cutoff = p;
        }
    }
    if (cutoff)
    {
        *cutoff = '\0';
    }

    return start;
}
```

---

`try_expand()`, `process_line()`, and `process_file()` can all be greatly simplified.  All of the code exists primarily to manage memory for reading lines of arbitrary length.  Fortunately, on POSIX platforms, you can just use [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/getdelim.html) to eliminate all of that drudgery.  In fact, you don't even need to `malloc()` anything at all.

Moreover, the fact that you need a loop in `process_line()` to search for `'\n'` makes the implementation not a one-pass algorithm as you claim.  (While doing line-oriented work requires scanning for the `'\n'`, the `getline()` interface tells you how long the line was, whereas the `fgets()` interface makes you hunt for `'\n'` all over again.)

For readability, you should use `size_t` instead of `int` for a variable that indicates the size of a buffer.

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Processes a file.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void process_file(char** p_buffer, size_t* p_buffer_length, FILE* file)
{
    while (-1 != getline(p_buffer, p_buffer_length, file))
    {
        puts(trim_inplace(*p_buffer));
    }
}
```

---

Error messages should be printed to `stderr` so as not to contaminate `stdout`.

You've already hard-coded `h` and `v` in the `check_flags()` function, so you are committed to using those letters anyway.  You might as well eliminate the `HELP_FLAG`, `VERSION_FLAG`, and `FLAG_DESC` macros to make the string more readable.

Instead of implementing `get_short_program_name()`, just call [`basename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html).  (And I would do it in `check_flags()` rather than `print_help()`.)

The `getopt()` function automatically prints a diagnostic message when an unrecognized flag is encountered.  If you wish to `print_bad_flags()` manually, then you should disable the redundant automatic message by setting `opterr = 0`.

Consider adding `-l` and `-t` flags to control whether to trim just leading whitespace or trailing whitespace.

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the help message and exits.                                           *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_help(const char* program_name, FILE *f)
{
    fprintf(f, "Usage: %s [-h] [-v] [FILE1, [FILE2, [...]]]\n"
               "    -h    Print this help message and exit.\n"
               "    -v    Print the version message and exit.\n"
               "    If no files specified, reads from standard input.\n",
               program_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the version string.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_version()
{
    printf("trim 1.6180\n" \
           "By Rodion \"rodde\" Efremov 10.04.2015 Helsinki\n");
}


/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the erroneous flag.                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_bad_flag(const char* flag)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown flag \"%s\"\n", flag);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Checks the flags.                                                            *
*******************************************************************************/
static void check_flags(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;

    opterr = 0;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "vh")) != -1)
    {
        switch (c) 
        {
            case 'v':
                print_version();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;

            case 'h':
                print_help(basename(argv[0]), stdout);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;

            case '?':
                print_bad_flag((char*) &optopt);
                print_help(basename(argv[0]), stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;

            default:
                abort();
        }
    }
}
```

---

`main()` looks generally fine.  You can now initialize `buffer_length = 0` and `buffer = NULL` for simplicity, since `getline()` takes care of memory allocation for you.

There was one comment, `// If realloc changes the location of memory, we need to know this.`, which I found puzzling.  I don't think it adds any value, so I recommend removing it.